# postgresql two nested joins and arrays in join

Tags: sql, arrays, json, node.js, postgresql

I've never had to ask an SO question before, I always eventually stumble upon what I'm looking for through searching, but there's a lot going on here and I've gotten to the end of my searching prowess... Thanks for your help / suggestions.

## The problem

I need to generate reports on the fly about how many 'students' in my organization have taken each 'assessment', and the standards associated with each 'assessment'.

- Student totals are calculated ahead of time and stored in assessments_report

  - The report row needs to be joined with the "assessment" to display info
- Standards have sub-standards, but assessments only know about the sub-standard.
- Assessments have multiple sub-standards and store them in an array of ids.

I'm trying to do this in the most performant way that minimizes the load on Postgres but I don't believe I've achieved that goal...

## The Setup

**Server:** Amazon EC2 running Ubuntu

**The App (Server):** Node.js (0.10.26)

**The App (Client):** Angular.js (1.2.13)

**Database (Queries):** PostgreSQL (9.3.1)

**Database (Cache):** MongoDB *(Hope to cache report in future)*

## The Tables

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/61fd2/11)**

**assessments**

```
_id                int4
description        text
category           varchar(60)
sub_standards      int4 ARRAY
...
```

**assessments_report** (pre-calculated sums)

```
assessment_id(FK)  int4
client_id(FK)      int4
students           int4
completed          int4
incomplete         int4
...
```

**sub_standards**

```
_id
standard_id(FK)    int4
description        varchar(255)
...
```

**standards**

```
_id                int4
name               varchar(60)
description        varchar(255)
...
```

## The Query

```
//Stored as array for readability in Node-Postgres use
SELECT r.*, as.* FROM assessments_report r
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT a._id AS assessment_id, a.description, a.category, a.states,
  array_to_json(array_agg(ss.*)) AS standards
  FROM assessments a LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ss.*, s.name AS parent_name, s.description AS parent_description
    FROM sub_standards ss
    INNER JOIN standards s ON ss.standard_id = s._id
  ) ss ON ss._id = ANY (a.sub_standards) GROUP BY a._id
) as
ON as.assessment_id = r.assessment_id
WHERE r.client_id = $1
```

## The Desired Output For Each Row (shown as JSON)

```
assessment_id: 2,
students: 2,
complete: 1
incomplete: 1,
description: "...",
category: "...",
states: ["AL","AZ",...],
standards: [
  {
    _id: 1,
    standard_id: 3,
    description: "...",
    parent_name: "...",
    parent_description: "..."
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    standard_id: 4,
    description: "...",
    parent_name: "...",
    parent_description: "..."
  },
]
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/61fd2/11)**

Comment: To usefully help optimize the query, usable schema + sample data (ideally a http://sqlfiddle.com/) would be strongly preferable. You should also show `explain analyze` output for your current query.

Comment: @CraigRinger Thanks for the call out! I've created [the fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/61fd2/9) and added it to the question. In it I got a little more specific about my setup and future improvements/changes, let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EXPLAIN` of your query produces a max cost of 537.  You can take that down to 59 (factor 10 improvement) by just creating an index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_sstandard_sid ON sub_standards (standard_id);
```

But this is even faster with a cost of 21:

```
WITH r AS (SELECT * FROM assessments_report WHERE client_id = $1)
, ss AS (SELECT r.*, a.description, a.category, a.states , a.sub_standards
    FROM r INNER JOIN assessments a ON a._id = r.assessment_id)
, ss3 AS (SELECT ss2.*, s.name parent_name, s.description parent_description
            FROM sub_standards ss2
            INNER JOIN standards s
            ON ss2.standard_id = s._id)
, ss1 AS (SELECT ss.*, array_to_json(array_agg(ss3.*)) standards
    FROM ss
    LEFT JOIN ss3
    ON ss3._id = ANY (ss.sub_standards)
    GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14 ) 
SELECT _id, client_id, region_id, group_id, assessment_id, students, basic, 
    proficient, advanced, in_progress, description, category, states, standards
FROM ss1;
```

You could probably get rid of the grouping and go somewhat faster than this.

The basic idea is to start with the most limiting constraint (client_id), expand that by the next criteria (sub_standards) and never expand the recordset any more than necessary after that.  Lookups against primary keys are faster than complex joins.
Hope this helps.

Final query plan:

```
CTE Scan on ss1  (cost=21.79..21.81 rows=1 width=434)
CTE r
->  Seq Scan on assessments_report  (cost=0.00..1.06 rows=1 width=40)
      Filter: (client_id = 4)
CTE ss
->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.14..8.19 rows=1 width=434)
      ->  CTE Scan on r  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=40)
      ->  Index Scan using assesments_pkey on assessments a  (cost=0.14..8.16 rows=1 width=398)
            Index Cond: (_id = r.assessment_id)
CTE ss3
->  Hash Join  (cost=1.07..12.34 rows=3 width=1346)
      Hash Cond: (s._id = ss2.standard_id)
      ->  Seq Scan on standards s  (cost=0.00..10.90 rows=90 width=818)
      ->  Hash  (cost=1.03..1.03 rows=3 width=532)
            ->  Seq Scan on sub_standards ss2  (cost=0.00..1.03 rows=3 width=532)
CTE ss1
->  HashAggregate  (cost=0.19..0.20 rows=1 width=462)
      ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.00..0.15 rows=1 width=462)
            Join Filter: (ss3._id = ANY (ss.sub_standards))
            ->  CTE Scan on ss  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=434)
            ->  CTE Scan on ss3  (cost=0.00..0.06 rows=3 width=32)
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer! The query has evolved a bit since I originally asked this question but I will evaluate your solution as soon as I can and accept the answer once I can confirm my intended output. Also my mistake in not creating the index on my SQL Fiddle, I do have that index in my local DB.